# How to check existence of primary key of ORM model in table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm attempting to check if the key of a particular entity (as defined with an ORM class) already exists in a database.

Note that it needs to work regardless of the names of the (key) attributes. It needs to work generically across all ORM models.

Here's the basic structure of what I need:

```py
# User class definition using ORM
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    USER_ID = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    ... # OTHER FIELDS EXIST HERE, NOT PART OF PRIMARY KEY
    

# We have a particular ORM instance
# We need to check if its PK exists in table
# Other fields may have any values
user_instance = User(USER_ID = 1)

# We have a session with DB
session = Session()

# ===

# Now, how do we check if User with USER_ID = 1 (dynamically - we might have different data)

# ===
```

I am aware of `sqlalchemy.inspect` but I'm not really sure how it would be applied in this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do here?  What will happen if the `id` already exists in the database?  Or if it doesn't?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I need to do this dynamically, as it is in the context of CDC upsert. If key exists, we perform update, if not, we insert.